How to NAT AWS EC2 instance IPv4 through site-to-site
I just create a AWS VPN site-to-site to connect with on-premise network.  I need the on-premise network see my EC2 instances with a different IP regarding the original IP they has in my AWS subnet.
Do you know how to do this?
